# ProxyPass custom port Redirect to https

Tags: linux, apache, redirect, vhosts, proxypass

I would like to grand access to certain IP's to mysite.com:1234 but deny that port to other users and redirect them to port 80 or 443, the first part is working with my vhosts file but I can't seem to get the redirection part working, other IP's get 403 error

```
<VirtualHost 12.123.123.123:443>


<Directory "/home/mysite/public_html">
            
    Options -Indexes -FollowSymLinks +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    AllowOverride All 
    SSLRequireSSL
</Directory>

<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyVia Full
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:1234/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:1234/

    <Proxy "http://127.0.0.1:1234/">
    
            Deny from all
            allow from 1.1.1.1
            allow from 1.1.1.2
            allow from 1.1.1.3
            allow from 1.1.1.4
    </Proxy>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to implement your proxy rule with mod_rewrite. Rewrite rules have a `[P]` flag which means "reverse proxy".  You could have a rewrite condition that checks for the correct IP addresses before a rule that does the proxy.  Then all other requests would fall through to a second rule that does the redirect.

```
RewriteEngine On

# Reverse proxy for allowed remote addresses
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^1.1.1.[1234]$
RewriteRule  ^/?(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:1234/$1  [P,L]

# Redirect everything else to the main site
RewriteRule  ^/?(.*)$ https://mysite.example/$1  [R=301,L]
```

Comment: it gives me internal server error unfortunately

Comment: I probably have a syntax error in there. Is there a message in the error log file?

Comment: I get 
`[Wed Apr 13 18:24:12.365308 2022] [core:error] [pid 2582:tid 140131520456448] [remote 168.1.11.111:443] AH01961:  failed to enable ssl support [Hint: if using mod_ssl, see SSLProxyEngine]
[Wed Apr 13 18:24:12.365383 2022] [proxy:error] [pid 2582:tid 140131520456448] AH00961: https: failed to enable ssl support for 168.1.11.111:443 (mywebsite.eu)`

Comment: The second rule should redirect, not proxy.  I updated the answer to change `[P]` to `[R=301]` .